# Counting the number of partitions having blocks of cardinality 2 and non-distinct elements

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a set of integers $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, then there exists $B_n$ partitions of this set where $B_n$ is a [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). For instance, there are $B_3$=5 partitions of the set $\{1,2,3\}$:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \Pi[\{1,2,3\}] &= \left[\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}+\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}\right.\\
                 &\qquad\left.
                  +\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}+\{\{1,3\},\{2\}\}+\{\{1,2,3\}\}\right].
  \end{align}
  $$
For a set having an even number of elements, what is the number of distinct partitions that consists only of blocks of cardinality 2 in the case:

- that all elements are distinct?
- some elements are repeated $k_i$ times?

In other words, how many partitions of a with $2n$ elements has $n$ blocks? What happens when some elements are repeated?

#### Clarification (if needed)

For instance, for a set containing four distinct elements, the distinct partitions having blocks of cardinality 2 are 
 $$
 \begin{align}
 \Pi_2[\{1,2,3,4\}] &= \left\{\{\{1,2\},\,\{3,4\}\}\right.\\
                    &\quad+ \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}\\
                    &\quad+\left.\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\}\right\}.
 \end{align}
 $$
It seems that there are $\frac{1}{2} {4 \choose 2}$ distinct partitions of a set with distinct that have blocks of cardinality 2.

How does it generalize to $n$ elements, and what if some elements are repeated? In particular, how many distinct partitions of $\{1,2,3,4,x,x,x,x\}$ are there?

#### Edit

I have found a partial answer to my questions in *A Walk Through Combinatorics*. Each partition can be assigned a type $a=(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_k)$ where $a_i$ is the cardinality of each block in a partition $\pi$. Then, the number of set partitions of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ of type $a$, $P_a$, is given by
 $$
 P_a = \frac{1}{\prod_i m_i!}{n\choose a_1,\cdots ,a_k}
 $$
where $m_i$ is the multiplicity of a given cardinality and we used the multinomial symbol. Since we are looking at set partitions having type $a=(2,2,2,\cdots,2)$ (the number of elements in the type is $n/2$), we can write this as
 $$
 P_{2,2,\cdots,2} = \frac{1}{(n/2)!}\frac{n!}{(2!)^{n/2}}
 $$
which indeed recovers the three partitions for $n=4$.

Comment: A set only have different elements. If elements are repeated then this isnt a set.

Comment: It's a multiset, then. So, given a multiset $\{n_1 x_1,\cdots, n_k x_k\}$ where $x_i$ are the elements and $n_i$ their multiplicities, what is the number of multiset partititions that are of type $a=(a_1,\cdots,a_\ell)$ where $a$ is an integer partition of $n=\sum_i n_i$ known as the type of the multiset partition.